# Node couples connected to only one type of nodes within a subgraph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to achieve the following but I can't quite figure out how to do this.

I have nodes of type `:A`, `:S1`, `:S2` :t and `:k`.

I want to find couples of `:t` nodes that are connected to an `:A` node and are never connected (both, of course) to `:S` or `:S1` nodes, but I want to do it in the subgraph where `:A`, `:S` and `:S1` nodes are connected to `(:k{t:1})`, another node.

Without the subgraph need it's pretty simple such as:

```
match p=(n:t)-[]-(:A)-[]-(m:t) 
WHERE NOT (n)-[]-(:S)-[]-(m) 
and NOT (n)-[]-(:S1)-[]-(m)
WITH n,m,count(p) as test
where test >4
return n.token,m.token,test ORDER BY test DESC
```

But how do I put in my

```
(:A)--(:k{t:1})
```

and

```
(:S)--(:k{t:1}),(:S1)--(:k{t:1})
```

relationships?

Answer (score 0):

What about simply `MATCH` the sub-graph first and after it `MATCH` the desired couple of n nodes?

This way:

```
// First MATCH (:A)--(:k{t:1}), (:S)--(:k{t:1}), (:S1)--(:k{t:1})
// Store the matched nodes in a, k, s and s1 variables
MATCH (a:A)--(k:k{t:1}),
(s:S)--(k),
(s1:S1)--(k)

// Using a, k, s and s1 match couple of n...
// connected with a
MATCH p = (n:t)--(a)--(m:t)
// not connected with s 
WHERE NOT (n)--(s)--(m)
// and not connected with s1
AND NOT (n)--(s1)--(m)
WITH n, m, count(p) as count
WHERE count > 4
RETURN n.token, m.token, count
ORDER BY count
```